# Magento 2.2.1 Checkout 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: magento, magento2, checkout, internal-server-error

Using Magento 2.2.1 freshly installed

I use php 7.1.1

I am using Adyen payment gateway
https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-magento2
the extension developer says its not due to their extension. I have enabled every php extension on server side thats needed. So now it comes to magento 2

Tried to checkout as guest and then I see

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

```
https://{siteurl.com}/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/1a41b8daeba4d90df7c5dca2085dd732/payment-information
When I try to use COD or Check the checkout process is smooth. Haven't tried with paypal or others
```

**Can you please help ??

If you need me to perform any steps in either server side or magento 2 please tell me the steps on what to do I will post the output here**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue

Solution : I used a third party extension and installed it through magento 2 admin directly which resulted the extension was not installed properly. I have used composer to install the extension and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I work for Adyen.

It is indeed required to install the Adyen plugin on Magento through Composer. This will include all the dependencies and prevent the issue that is shown here. 
For further references you could visit our Github page: 
https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-magento2

Hope that it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the unexpected error (e.g 500), we should enable error reporting on the bootstrap:

app/bootstrap.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1) // enable this line remove # from start.
```

you will get the real issue on screen